# Merge sub array with same keys values

Tags: php

I've got an array with some sub arrays, what I'm trying to achieve is merging subarrays of they have the same value for a specific key

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 57
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 4.470
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 56
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 45.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 74
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 79.000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 75
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 26.000
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 74
            [Tabella gruppo B] => 201.000
        )
)
```

And this is how I would like it look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 57
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 4.470
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 56
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 45.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 74
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 79.000
            [Tabella gruppo B] => 201.000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 75
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 26.000
        )

)
```

As you can see for building ID 74 I need to merge the two sub arrays into one sub array.

This is my SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id,
                               km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id,
                               km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value,
                               km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name

                               FROM km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values

                               LEFT JOIN  km_kondomanager_millesimal_table
                               ON km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values . km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id = km_kondomanager_millesimal_table . km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_id";

                $query= mysqli_prepare($db_user_conn, $sql);
                // mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'i', $km_group_id);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $km_building_id, $km_table_id, $millesimal_value, $millesimal_table_name);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($query);

                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) { 


                    $responses[] = array(

                        'Building ID' => $km_building_id,
                        $millesimal_table_name => $millesimal_value

                      );

                }
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($responses as $values) {
    $key = $values['Building ID'];
    $output[$key][] = $values;

}

// Don't want the referenceUid in the keys? Reset them:
$output = array_values($output);
```

And it returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Building ID] => 74
                    [Tabella gruppo A] => 79.000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Building ID] => 74
                    [Tabella gruppo B] => 201.000
                )

        )
)
```

Table data:

```
INSERT INTO `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_values` (`km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_table_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_millesimal_value`) VALUES
(95, 9, 74, '79.000'),
(96, 9, 75, '26.000'),
(97, 9, 76, '90.000'),
(98, 9, 77, '98.000'),
(99, 9, 78, '52.000'),
(100, 9, 79, '55.000'),
(101, 9, 80, '55.000'),
(102, 9, 81, '58.000'),
(103, 9, 82, '61.000'),
(104, 9, 83, '64.000'),
(105, 9, 84, '59.000'),
(106, 9, 85, '62.000'),
(107, 9, 86, '64.000'),
(108, 9, 87, '62.000'),
(109, 9, 88, '59.000'),
(110, 9, 89, '56.000'),
(111, 10, 74, '201.000'),
(112, 10, 75, '32.000'),
(113, 10, 76, '0.000'),
(114, 10, 77, '0.000'),
(115, 10, 78, '63.000'),
(116, 10, 79, '67.000'),
(117, 10, 80, '47.000'),
(118, 10, 81, '49.000'),
(119, 10, 82, '51.000'),
(120, 10, 83, '53.000'),
(121, 10, 84, '55.000'),
(122, 10, 85, '59.000'),
(123, 10, 86, '60.000'),
(124, 10, 87, '58.000'),
(125, 10, 88, '105.000'),
(126, 10, 89, '100.000');

INSERT INTO `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table` (`km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_name`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_desc`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_group_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_palazzina_id`, `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_scala_id`) VALUES
(4, 'Tabella generale', 'Tabella generale dei millesimi per tutte le unità immobiliari del condominio', 13, NULL, NULL),
(5, 'Tabella scala A', 'Tabella millesimale per le unità immobiliari della scala A', 13, 7, 1),
(6, 'Tabella scala B', 'Tabella millesimale per le unità immobiliari della scala B', 13, 8, 2),
(8, 'Tabella palazzina uno', 'Questa tabella è specifica solo per la palazzina uno', 13, 7, NULL),
(9, 'Tabella gruppo A', 'Tabella gruppo A', 15, 11, NULL),
(10, 'Tabella gruppo B', 'Tabella gruppo B', 15, 11, NULL);
```

This is the HTML table i'm triying to build
[image]

Comment: if this is coming from sql, more efficient to do it with a query i'd bet

Comment: Hi @Alex yes it come from SQL, I need to build a HTML table

Comment: Use group by `Building ID` and use `concat`  with comma to get the result using query. Later on use PHP `explode` for `concat` field

Comment: Hi I've edited the question and added the SQL query from where the array comes from

Comment: I feel sorry for anyone having to maintain this database - with field names like `km_kondomanager_millesimal_table_value_building_id` it is so easy to make a mistake in typing field names.

Comment: Hi @RakeshJakhar could you help me with SQL query? many thanks

Comment: @pippo please share some of the data of both tables.

Comment: Hi @RakeshJakhar I've edited the question with the table datas I did a mysql export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php
$arrSrc = array(
    array(
        "Building ID" => 57,
        "Tabella palazzina uno" => 4.470
    ),

    array(
        "Building ID" => 56,
        "Tabella palazzina uno" => 45.000
    ),

    array(
        "Building ID" => 74,
        "Tabella gruppo A" => 79.000
    ),

    array(
        "Building ID" => 75,
        "Tabella gruppo A" => 26.000
    ),
    array(
        "Building ID" => 74,
        "Tabella gruppo B" => 201.000
    )
);

$arrDest = array();
$cnt = count( $arrSrc );
for( $i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++ )
{
    $curArr = $arrSrc[ $i ];
    $idValue = "";
    $sumKey = "";
    $sumValue = "";
    foreach( $curArr as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $key == "Building ID" )
        {
            $idValue = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $sumKey = $key;
            $sumValue = $value;
        }
    }

    //echo( "\n" . $idValue );
    //echo( "\n" . $sumKey );
    //echo( "\n" . $sumValue );
    if( isset( $arrDest[ $idValue ] ) == false )
    {
        $arrDest[ $idValue ] = array();
    }
    if( isset( $arrDest[ $idValue ][ $sumKey ] ) == false )
    {
        $arrDest[ $idValue ][ $sumKey ] = 0.0;
    }
    $arrDest[ $idValue ][ $sumKey ] += $sumValue;
}
echo print_r( $arrDest, true );

$arrDest2 = array();
foreach( $arrDest as $key => $value )
{
    $tmpArr = array( "Building ID" => $key );
    foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 )
    {
        $tmpArr[$key2] = $value2;
    }
    $arrDest2[] = $tmpArr;
}

echo print_r( $arrDest2, true );

?>
```

First result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [57] => Array
        (
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 4.47
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 45
        )

    [74] => Array
        (
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 79
            [Tabella gruppo B] => 201
        )

    [75] => Array
        (
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 26
        )

)
```

Second result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 57
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 4.47
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 56
            [Tabella palazzina uno] => 45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 74
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 79
            [Tabella gruppo B] => 201
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Building ID] => 75
            [Tabella gruppo A] => 26
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi @Rufat thanks for your answer this is quite exactly what I was trying to do. I've notice that the building ID is the key of each array, is it possible to have the array indexes as [0], [1] and keep the building ID as one of the arrays options like [Building ID] => 74, [Tabella gruppo A] => 26, [Tabella gruppo B] => 32 many thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @pippo, see code above, I improved the code as you requested.